# ListPicker Data Showing in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, listpicker

I am writing Windows Phone 8.1 app, I have binded listpicker with data, those data come from web service result, now, my problem is that, there are plenty and too much records, and therefore my app gets crash. How do I show just " 1 to 50" records?

See my code below:

```
XDocumnet doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

List<string> list = new List<string>();

list = (from query in doc.Descendants("row")
       select new string
       {
           Id = query.Element("Id").Value,
           Name = query.Element("Name").Value
        }).ToList();

listPicker1.ItemsSource = list;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Take

```
listPicker1.ItemsSource = list.Take(50);
```